# Flutter pop route in 2 different cases

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

Let's say I have 4 screen: A, B, C, D, E.

-Case 1: I did something on screen E then back to screen C, example:

[image: Case 1]

To do this, I used Navigator.popUntil(), but there's case 2 like this:

-Case 2: Go to screen E from A then D, did something and go back to C, example:

[image: Case 2]

To do this, I used Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(). Is there a way to check if I have added route C before, to cancel pushNamed action in case 2? Sorry for my bad explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't understand what you're trying to do in my case in routing I use this package
 [Fluro router](https://pub.dev/packages/fluro#-readme-tab-) and personally I think the documentation is hard to follow so here's a guide that I've found  [Guide on how to use fluro](https://medium.com/flutter-community/navigate-like-youre-on-the-web-in-flutter-using-fluro-ad70d28042c6)